# Linq Where condition is not working properly using EF

Tags: c#, json, linq

been trying to figure out what is wrong with my query and have been playing a round with the Where condition but to no luck. Below is my query inside the controller file.

```
ValueStory valuestory = await db.ValueStories.FindAsync(id);

//Area Of Interest Value Drivers
var aoivaluedriver = (from AOIValueDrivers in db.AOIValueDrivers
                      join aoivd in db.AOIValueDrivers on AOIValueDrivers.AOIVDId equals aoivd.AOIId
                      join aoi in db.AreaOfInterests on aoivd.AOIId equals aoi.AOIId
                      join vs in db.ValueStories on aoi.Id equals vs.Id
                      where aoivd.AOIId == aoi.AOIId && aoi.Id == vs.Id && vs.Id == id
                      select aoivd
                      ).ToList();

List<AOIValueDrivers> aoivd1 = new List<AOIValueDrivers>();
foreach (var a in aoivaluedriver)
{
    aoivd1.Add(new AOIValueDrivers()
    {
        AOIVDId = a.AOIVDId,
        Item = a.Item,
        SubItem = a.SubItem,
        Value = a.Value,
        AOIId = a.AOIId

    });
}
//Area pf Interest  Value Drivers End


//Area Of Interest
var areaOfInterest = (from AreaOfInterest in db.AreaOfInterests
                      join aoi in db.AreaOfInterests on AreaOfInterest.AOIId equals aoi.AOIId
                      join vs in db.ValueStories on aoi.Id equals vs.Id
                      where aoi.Id == vs.Id && vs.Id == id
                      select aoi
                      //{
                      // AOIName = aoe.AOIName,
                      //ValueDriver = aoe.ValueDriver
                      //}
                             ).ToList();

List<AreaOfInterest> aoi1 = new List<AreaOfInterest>();
foreach (var a in areaOfInterest)
{
    aoi1.Add(new AreaOfInterest()
    {
        AOIId = a.AOIId,
        AOIName = a.AOIName,
        Selected = a.Selected,
        Id = a.Id,
        AOIValueDrivers = aoivd1

    });
}
```

the result in my Json is it lists all of my aoivaluedriver data ang ignores my Where condition. here is the Json output

```
{
  "AreaOfInterest": [
    {
      "AOIId": 1,
      "AOIName": "Supply Chain/ Direct Materials",
      "Selected": true,
      "Id": 1,
      "ValueStory": null,
      "AOIValueDrivers": [
        {
          "AOIVDId": 1,
          "Item": "Negotiate better prices & conditions",
          "SubItem": "Automate the process of sourcing of direct materials and integrate it to you ERP and key execution systems",
          "Value": 3,
          "AOIId": 1,
          "AreaOfInterest": null
        },
        {
          "AOIVDId": 2,
          "Item": "Lower Cost",
          "SubItem": "Reduct costs of supply chain FTEs",
          "Value": 3,
          "AOIId": 1
        },
        {
          "AOIVDId": 10,
          "Item": "Negotiate better prices & conditions",
          "SubItem": "Foster supplier competition to reduce pricing and obtain best market value",
          "Value": 3,
          "AOIId": 2
        },
        {
          "AOIVDId": 19,
          "Item": "Negotiate better prices & conditions",
          "SubItem": "Control and maximise savings on non strategically source spend",
          "Value": 3,
          "AOIId": 3
        },
        {
          "AOIVDId": 24,
          "Item": "Buy and pay at the negotiated rate & conditions",
          "SubItem": "Reduce invoice matching exceptions (to contracts, orders, & receipts)",
          "Value": 3,
          "AOIId": 4
        },
        {
          "AOIVDId": 34,
          "Item": "Free up working capital",
          "SubItem": "Offer suppliers options to get paid quicker while not reducing DPO",
          "Value": 3,
          "AOIId": 5
        },
        {
          "AOIVDId": 38,
          "Item": "Protect your revenue",
          "SubItem": "Access to systems such as Dun & Bradstreet to certify suppliers",
          "Value": 3,
          "AOIId": 6
        },
        {
          "AOIVDId": 43,
          "Item": "nothing",
          "SubItem": "nothing",
          "Value": 0,
          "AOIId": 7
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

the expected result is that it should only return all items with AOIId = 1 but instead its returning all the items in the table. what could be wrong with my query? Still very new to EF and Linq and still trying to get myself familiar with  it.

here is the db modeling for my areaofinterest

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AreaOfInterest] (
    [AOIId]    INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AOIName]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Selected] BIT            NOT NULL,
    [Id]       INT            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AreaOfInterest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AOIId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AreaOfInterest_dbo.ValueStory_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ValueStory] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Id]
    ON [dbo].[AreaOfInterest]([Id] ASC);
```

and here's the one for areaofinterestvaluedriver

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AOIValueDrivers] (
    [AOIVDId] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Item]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [SubItem] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Value]   INT            NOT NULL,
    [AOIId]   INT            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AOIValueDrivers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AOIVDId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AOIValueDrivers_dbo.AreaOfInterest_AOIId] FOREIGN KEY ([AOIId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AreaOfInterest] ([AOIId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AOIId]
    ON [dbo].[AOIValueDrivers]([AOIId] ASC);
```

the expected json output should be like this

```
{
  "AreaOfInterest": [
    {
      "AOIId": 1,
      "AOIName": "Supply Chain/ Direct Materials",
      "Selected": true,
      "Id": 1,
      "ValueStory": null,
      "AOIValueDrivers": [
        {
          "AOIVDId": 1,
          "Item": "Negotiate better prices & conditions",
          "SubItem": "Automate the process of sourcing of direct materials and integrate it to you ERP and key execution systems",
          "Value": 3,
          "AOIId": 1,
          "AreaOfInterest": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
   "AreaOfInterest": [
    {
      "AOIId": 2,
      "AOIName": "Supply Chain/ Direct Materials",
      "Selected": true,
      "Id": 1,
      "ValueStory": null,
      "AOIValueDrivers": [
        {
          "AOIVDId": 10,
          "Item": "Negotiate better prices & conditions",
          "SubItem": "Foster supplier competition to reduce pricing and obtain best market value",
          "Value": 3,
          "AOIId": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
    "AreaOfInterest": [
    {
      "AOIId": 3,
      "AOIName": "Supply Chain/ Direct Materials",
      "Selected": true,
      "Id": 1,
      "ValueStory": null,
      "AOIValueDrivers": [
        {
          "AOIVDId": 19,
          "Item": "Negotiate better prices & conditions",
          "SubItem": "Control and maximise savings on non strategically source spend",
          "Value": 3,
          "AOIId": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

this is how my model looks:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebService.Models
{
    public class AreaOfInterest
    {


        [Key]
        public int AOIId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string AOIName { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }

        // Foreign Key
        public int Id { get; set; }
        // Navigation property
        public virtual ValueStory ValueStory { get; set; }

        //Value Drivers AOI for the Value Story
        public List<AOIValueDrivers> AOIValueDrivers { get; set; }

    }

    public class AOIValueDrivers
    {
        [Key]
        public int AOIVDId { get; set; }
        public string Item { get; set; }
        public string SubItem { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }

        // Foreign Key
        public int AOIId { get; set; }
        // Navigation property
        public virtual AreaOfInterest AreaOfInterest { get; set; }

    }

}
```

this is the working code

```
      //Area Of Interest Value Drivers
      var aoivaluedriver = (from AOIValueDrivers in db.AOIValueDrivers
                            join aoivd in db.AOIValueDrivers on AOIValueDrivers.AOIVDId equals aoivd.AOIId
                            join aoi in db.AreaOfInterests on aoivd.AOIId equals aoi.AOIId
                            select aoivd
                            ).ToList();

      List<AOIValueDrivers> aoivd1 = new List<AOIValueDrivers>();
      foreach (var a in aoivaluedriver)
      {
          aoivd1.Add(new AOIValueDrivers()
          {
              AOIVDId = a.AOIVDId,
              Item = a.Item,
              SubItem = a.SubItem,
              Value = a.Value,
              AOIId = a.AOIId

          });
      }
    //Area pf Interest  Value Drivers End

    //Area Of Interest
    var areaOfInterest = (from AreaOfInterest in db.AreaOfInterests
                          join aoi in db.AreaOfInterests on AreaOfInterest.AOIId equals aoi.AOIId
                          join vs in db.ValueStories on aoi.Id equals vs.Id
                          where aoi.Id == vs.Id && vs.Id == id
                          select aoi).ToList();



    List<AreaOfInterest> aoi1 = new List<AreaOfInterest>();
    foreach (var a in areaOfInterest)
    {
        aoi1.Add(new AreaOfInterest()
        {
            AOIId = a.AOIId,
            AOIName = a.AOIName,
            Selected = a.Selected,
            Id = a.Id,
            AOIValueDrivers = aoivd1?.Where(vd => vd.AOIId == a.AOIId)?.ToList()

        });
    }
    //Area pf Interest End
```

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense. Why are you self joining to `db.AreaOfInterests` then joining that to `db.ValueStories` but never using the values `db.ValueStories`?

Comment: Can you post your database modeling for those tables? I think you are having a lazy loading problem because of you tables relationship.

Comment: @Erick, i've updated my post with the database structure

Comment: @David, the Id in db.ValueStories is my Get id reference for the json array

Comment: Yes, but you're not selecting any of the `db.ValueStories`, instead you are lazy loading them form the parent which cannot be filtered.

Comment: @DavidG: Can this join not be used as a way to filter items (i.e. keep only the items with a related ValueStory)? I agree that joins shouldn't be used like this (that's what the Where clause is for), but it's possible that that was the OP's intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try to simplify things here.

Take advantage of the Entity Framework lazy loading approach and modeling, and I'm supposing that you entities modeling is right, you could do something like (just an example).

```
//Area Of Interest
var areaOfInterest = (from AreaOfInterest in db.AreaOfInterests.Include(a => a.AOIValueDrivers)
                      join aoi in db.AreaOfInterests on AreaOfInterest.AOIId equals aoi.AOIId
                      join vs in db.ValueStories on aoi.Id equals vs.Id
                      where aoi.Id == vs.Id && vs.Id == id
                      select aoi).ToList();


List<AreaOfInterest> aoi1 = new List<AreaOfInterest>();
foreach (var a in areaOfInterest)
{
    aoi1.Add(new AreaOfInterest()
    {
        AOIId = a.AOIId,
        AOIName = a.AOIName,
        Selected = a.Selected,
        Id = a.Id,
        AOIValueDrivers = a.AOIValueDrivers.Where(vd => vd.AOIId == a.AOIId).ToList()
    });
}
```

You don't need to do two queries, because when you do a select on a entity that have other entities related the relationship is lazy loaded by the entity framework.

Find more about it here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx and here http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx

Comment: I have tried this but I am getting a CS0266 error:
cannot implicity convert type 'system.collections.generic.ienumerable<webservice.models.AOIValueDrivers>' to 'System.collections.generic.list<webservice.models.AOIValueDrivers'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
pertaining to this line:
a.AOIValueDrivers.Where(vd => vd.AOIId == a.AOIId)

Comment: tried it earlier but i am getting this error when I run it on Postman:
[link] https://ibb.co/gsda4k

Comment: Check if `a.AOIValueDrivers` is null, if it is than your lazy loading is turn to false.

Try putting this `a.AOIValueDrivers?.Where(vd => vd.AOIId == a.AOIId)?.ToList()` to prevent null references and check if you are getting null objects

Comment: just in case, I've updated my post including my model class for this

Comment: Yes, AOIValueDrivers is Null.
I've also set lazyloading to true in my context.cs
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;

Comment: Hmm, ok, try put `.Include(a => a.AOIValueDrivers) ` check if this work for you.

Comment: you mean to add in the query?
join a in db.AOIValueDrivers on aoi.AOIId equals a.AOIId

Comment: See my edit. I'm assuming `db.AreaOfInterests` is your `DbSet<AreaOfInterests>`

Comment: I've updated my post for the working code. Do you think we can still improve that? If that is the best solution. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: For information, this is very bad practice. Because of the `ToList` you are now dragging the entire set of `AOIValueDrivers` into memory and filtering there rather than in the database.

Comment: @DavidG yes, there's a lot of better approaches to solve the query situation using EntityFramework. I just aimed to solve our friend problem using what he have already.

Comment: @RaymundEvangelista This is not the best solution for query using the Entity Framework. This solves your problem but we have a lot of better design patterns to apply to entity framework query. Since your question is answered on this topic you can either open a new question to discuss a better design solution for your problem, or send me a private message for us work on your code.

Comment: @ErickGallani You should never suggest it though. It leads to laziness and bad practice.

Comment: @Erick, appreciate the feedback. I will send a private message when necessary.

Comment: @DavidG, yes I also agree, that is the reason why I am asking for a better approach. But I appreciate your and Erick's response.

Comment: @DavidG, By the way, for this  case, what would you suggest to fix this in line with the best practices?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand much but as per the code your linq query is not correct. where clause in the query is wrong.

If you want the items with AOIID == 1 then the below code will work.

```
var aoivaluedriver = (from AOIValueDrivers in db.AOIValueDrivers
                  join aoivd in db.AOIValueDrivers on AOIValueDrivers.AOIVDId equals aoivd.AOIId
                  join aoi in db.AreaOfInterests on aoivd.AOIId equals aoi.AOIId
                  join vs in db.ValueStories on aoi.Id equals vs.Id
                  where aoivd.AOIId == 1
                  select aoivd
                  ).ToList();
```

-Gagan
https://blossomprogramming.blogspot.in/

Comment: I already tried that. I updated by post and included the expected json output.